# Data Driven TestNG Passing in parameters from excel

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I Am trying to pass in parameters from excel using a data driven approach using TestNG. My code runs fine, however, when my test gets to the section were the parameters are to be passed in to the fields on my form, they aren't passed in. My code is below for opening excel reading etc. And my Test code. I don't have excel installed as I have been creating spreadsheets in google sheets and exporting to xlsx. I am wondering if my issue is that I don't have excel installed so the file cant be opened and read and then the parameters passed in?

```
package utility;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class ExcelUtils {

            private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

            private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

            private static XSSFCell Cell;

            private static XSSFRow Row;



   public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {

               try {



                    FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);



                    ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

                    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

                    } catch (Exception e){

                        throw (e);

                    }

            }

        public static Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName, int iTestCaseRow)    throws Exception

        {   

           String[][] tabArray = null;

           try{

               FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);



               ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

               ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

               int startCol = 1;

               int ci=0,cj=0;

               int totalRows = 1; //Number of total rows in Data Sheet

               int totalCols = 3; //Number of columns in Data Sheet - Columns start from 0

               tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];

                   for (int j=startCol;j<=totalCols;j++, cj++)

                   {

                       tabArray[ci][cj]=getCellData(iTestCaseRow,j);

                       System.out.println(tabArray[ci][cj]);

                   }

            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e)

            {

                System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch (IOException e)

            {

                System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return(tabArray);

        }



        public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{

           try{

              Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);

              String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();

              return CellData;

              }catch (Exception e){

                return"";

                }

            }

        public static String getTestCaseName(String sTestCase)throws Exception{

            String value = sTestCase;

            try{

                int posi = value.indexOf("@");

                value = value.substring(0, posi);

                posi = value.lastIndexOf(".");  

                value = value.substring(posi + 1);

                return value;

                    }catch (Exception e){

                throw (e);

                        }

            }

        public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum) throws Exception{

            int i;

            try {

                int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowUsed();

                for ( i=0 ; i<rowCount; i++){

                    if  (ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,colNum).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)){

                        break;

                    }

                }

                return i;

                    }catch (Exception e){

                throw(e);

                }

            }

        public static int getRowUsed() throws Exception {

                try{

                    int RowCount = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();

                    return RowCount;

                }catch (Exception e){

                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    throw (e);

                }

            }

}
```

Test Code is Below:

```
package utility;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProviderWithExcel_001 {

    private String sTestCaseName;

    private int iTestCaseRow;

    WebDriver driver;

    private static Logger logger1 = LogManager.getLogger("Logger1");

    @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {

         DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

          driver = new FirefoxDriver();

          logger1.info("New Instance of firefox created");
          //Add wait to allow web elements to load

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          logger1.info("Timeout Applied for 10 seconds to Allow Load of Elements");
          //Launch FireFoxDriver - Open WebPage

          driver.get("http://localhost/2010A15/");

          logger1.info("Website Launched");
          Reporter.log("Website Lauched Successfully  | "); //Main Event Logger/Report 

    }

  @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
  public void f(String sUsername, String sPassword, String sMemorableWord)  {



    //Find Login Element
      driver.findElement(By.id("WEB_LoginButton")).click();

      logger1.info("Login Button Clicked");
      //Find User name Element

      driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1")).sendKeys(sUsername);

      logger1.info("Username Entered");

      //Find Password Element

      driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_2")).sendKeys(sPassword);

      logger1.info("Password Entered");

      //Find Memorable word Element

      driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_3")).sendKeys(sMemorableWord);

      logger1.info("MemorableWord Entered");

      Reporter.log("All Login Details Entered  | "); //Main Event

      WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));


      //If statement - will check if element is Displayed before clicking on login button.
      if(login.isDisplayed()){
          login.click();
          //Main Event is logged If Passed
          Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
          logger1.info("Submit Button Clicked");
      }else{  

          Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
          Assert.fail("Login Failed - Check Data | ");
          //Main Event Log Fail  
         }  




    WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));

    if(logout.isDisplayed()){
        logout.click();
    Reporter.log("Logout Successful  | ");
    }else {
        Reporter.log("Logout Failed");
        Assert.fail("Logout Failed - Check Data | ");
    }


    logger1.info("Logout Successful");


  }





  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {

     driver.close();
  }


  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] Authentication() throws Exception {

      // Setting up the Test Data Excel file

        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//Practice-test//src//testData//TestData.xlsx","Sheet1");

        sTestCaseName = this.toString();

        // From above method we get long test case name including package and class name etc.

        // The below method will refine your test case name, exactly the name use have used

        sTestCaseName = ExcelUtils.getTestCaseName(this.toString());

        // Fetching the Test Case row number from the Test Data Sheet

        // Getting the Test Case name to get the TestCase row from the Test Data Excel sheet

        iTestCaseRow = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseName,0);

        Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//Practice-test//src//testData//TestData.xlsx","Sheet1",iTestCaseRow);

            return (testObjArray);

        }
}
```

Comment: So there is no excel where you pointed path?

Comment: There is a .xlsx file, however, i've added C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//Practice-test//src//testData//TestData.xlsx to the FileInputStream, however am not sure if I need to add the path somwhere else also in the function file. Still new to TESTNG and new to data driven testing.

Comment: No need to add some where else , Do you getting `FilenotFound Exception?`

Comment: No I get: 
FAILED: f("", "", ""). So I presume its not passing in the parameters? Do you need Microsoft excel for this as I dont have it, I am just converting a google sheet file to a .xlsx file.

Comment: I've fixed it. the Test Case name did not match the test name in the excel file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Test Case name did not match the test name in the excel file.